# Is NetworkBoundResource still a valid approach?

Tags: android, flutter

Some years ago, the Android Team proposed a class called `NetworkBoundResource` to act as a resource backed by both the database and the network. The database would be a source of truth for data and fetch data from the network when certain conditions are met.

An example of `NetworkBoundResource` is available [here](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/repository/NetworkBoundResource.kt). However, that class isn't referred to in the [Android's Guide to Architecture](https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture) anymore. `RemoteMediator` is now referenced in the [guide](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/v3-network-db).

Is `NetworkBoundResource` still a valid approach if the Paging library isn't used on Android? Is this approach valid in Flutter, or is there a better way to achieve it?